# laravel payment gross amount not match items price

Tags: php, laravel, payment-gateway

I have payment getaway (code below)

```
public function orderspayonline(Request $request, $id){
      error_log('masuk ke snap token dri ajax');
      $midtrans = new Midtrans;

      $item = Order::findOrFail($id);
      $buyer = $item->buyer_name;
      $address = $item->address;
      $city = $item->city;
      $postalcode = $item->postalcode;
      $province = $item->province;
      $email = $item->buyer_email;
      $phone = $item->phone;
      $carttotal = $item->price;
      $shipping = $item->shipping_cost;

      $transaction_details = array(
          'order_id'      => uniqid(),
          'gross_amount'  => $carttotal,
// gross amount (total price buyer has to pay) is saved in order raw included shipping method like: (total price + weight * shipping cost).

      );


      // getting orders items detail
      $item_details = array();
      if(!empty($item->product_data)){ //product_data is my json column
        foreach($item->product_data as $item)
        {
          //calculate items price
          foreach($item['attributes'] as $itemsss)
          {
            $proweight = $itemsss['value'];
          }
          $pp = $item['quantity'] * $proweight * $shipping + $item['price'];
          //end calculation
            $item_details[] = array(
                'id'        => $item['id'],
                'price'     => $pp,
                'quantity'  => $item['quantity'],
                'name'      => $item['name'],
            );
        }
      }else{
        $item_details[] = array(
                'id'        => $item->id,
                'price'     => $item->price,
                'quantity'  => $item->quantity,
                'name'      => $item->product,
        );
      }

// to be continued....
```

now as you see in my `//getting orders items detail` part i have 2 type of loop, `first one` will loop orders with json based details `second one` will loop orders which created manually for users by admins which data is not json.

Previously I added `//calculate items price` as to get order weight and shipping price calculated with items price, in that case my gross amount would be same as my items price and everything works just fine without any error.

## Issue

The problem occurs when I have more than one item in my json based orders then my customized loop would not work any more and i get error of `gross_amount` not same as `items_price`.

any idea where should i change?

## UPDATE

my json code of order with multiple item

```
{"4":{"id":4,"name":"product four","price":1500000,"quantity":2,"attributes":{"attr":{"name":"weight","value":"45"}},"conditions":[],"_conditions":[{"name":"Black","value":"10000"},{"name":"12 inch","value":"25000"}]},"1":{"id":1,"name":"product one","price":10000000,"quantity":"1","attributes":{"attr":{"name":"weight","value":"1"}},"conditions":[{}],"_conditions":[{"name":"Black","value":"10000"}]}}
```

my json code of order with one item

```
{"4":{"id":4,"name":"product four","price":1535000,"quantity":"1","attributes":{"attr":{"name":"weight","value":"45"}},"conditions":[{},{}],"_conditions":[{"name":"Black","value":"10000"},{"name":"12 inch","value":"25000"}]}}
```

[image: screen1]

## UPDATE 2

`gross amount`

my `gross_amount` come from column named `price` value of that is sum of:

```
shipping cost * cart total weight + cart total amount
```

cart total amount might be included extra options added to items, or coupons reduced from items prices.

**the trick i used is:**

Getting that complete price (up) as my `gross amount` in order to get shipping price from customer as well, but the problem is my gateway company insist that my `gross_amount` and `items_price` be the exact same which doen't make seance to me because i have to get shipping cost as well.

So the trick was manipulate with items price in order to raise them till sum of them riches my `gross_amount` which i did by adding:

```
$pp = $item['quantity'] * $proweight * $shipping + $item['price'];
```

> now I realized that I didn't included those extra options/coupon codes
>   values

`you can find them in _conditions in my sample codes above` in my `$pp` and that's why items price sum never riches to `gross_amount`.

any idea how to add them as well?

Comment: Problem seems unclear, can you explain please.

Comment: @SagarGautam problem is on json orders which have more than 1 item it it, example order `5` has 3 items. then I cannot calculate total price of each item in that order.

Comment: I think your inner foreach loop has some problem, you are doing nothing there

Comment: @SagarGautam ok i explain it more. my json order is like `{id:2,name:product two,price:1000,attributes:{name:weight,value:2}}` first loop is to get access to that `2` kg in order to calculate my product weight with shipping cost and item price. that's it. now if i have 2 item in that column this loop become useless, is working only if i have 1 item.

Comment: I still don't understand last few lines. I'm sorry

Comment: @SagarGautam which part?

Comment: to be precise, last one

Comment: @SagarGautam `if(!empty($item->product_data)){` is looping my json orders, `}else{
        $item_details[] = array(` is getting info of orders which are not json (`admin created them manually`). `if(!empty($item->product_data)){` works only if i have 1 product ordered and saved in that json, if i have more than 1 product in that order will not work.

Comment: Can you add sample data when `$item->product_data` has more than one product ?

Comment: @SagarGautam sure./

Comment: @SagarGautam updated my question

Comment: I've seen that. What do you need actually, sum of values in an order ? if so you need to add those values in the loop.

Comment: @SagarGautam values are added `$pp = $item['quantity'] * $proweight * $shipping + $item['price'];` what i need is to get these values from all of the items not only one of them. currently it gets these value from only one item. that's why i have problem when i have more than one item.

Comment: I want to add some codes as answer wait a minute.

Comment: I've added my answer since you have to add up the costs for each item when you have more than one item. Have a look at that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your shipping costs are based on the weight of the products and quantity so you need to change your code like this,

```
// getting orders items detail
  $item_details = array();
  if(!empty($item->product_data)){ //product_data is my json column
    $pp = 0;
    foreach($item->product_data as $item)
    {
      //calculate items price
      foreach($item['attributes'] as $itemsss)
      {
        $proweight = $itemsss['value'];
      }
      $pp = $pp + $item['quantity'] * $proweight * $shipping + $item['price'];
      //end calculation
        $item_details[] = array(
            'id'        => $item['id'],
            'price'     => $pp,
            'quantity'  => $item['quantity'],
            'name'      => $item['name'],
        );
    }
  }
```

Comment: gross_amount not match with items_price

Comment: @mafortis one question, why should it match after adding shipping cost ?

Comment: the way this gateway works! i also complained about this to them too, but this is the way they made their system. I told them payable price never matchs items price because shipping cost will added but no result\

Comment: Ooh, I see but when you add shipping cost it will differ for sure.

Comment: And are you sure when there is only one then all works perfectly ?

Comment: @mafortis Okay I'll see

Comment: I saved my total price of items cost,shipping cost and times to weight of total items so i have final price in one column `which i get it as gross_amount`, and thats why I have `$pp` to make my items price higher till rich that total price :)

Comment: @mafortis Did you got solution ?

Comment: for 1 item in my json yes i get result but for multiple items in my json no, that's why i asked this question.

Comment: just idea: maybe we should make `$item->product_data` like `$item->product_data = array();` before foreach?

Comment: @mafortis no, because it will empty the data.

Comment: @mafortis did you include item quantity while calculating gross amount and saving to database table column ?

Comment: i must put that `$item->product_data = array();` before my foreach :-D

Comment: @mafortis congrats but must take a good test and then make sure about it works :D :D

Comment: Thanks dude, I am testing it currently to see what happens on different conditions. and for your wonder, see i have foreach of my items which gets 1 item so I convert it to array in order to loop all items and not only 1.

Comment: @mafortis ha ha I don't know what's happening there, you should give me a party for that :P :D

Comment: no, and i realized something now, my items might have `_conditions` just as they have `attributes` value of _conditions might sum or minus in `$pp` as well.

Comment: @mafortis Quite confusing for me right now, things are messed up

Answer (score 0):

## SOLVED

I changed my function to code below:

```
if(!empty($item->product_data)){
          foreach($item->product_data as $item)
          {
            //calculate items price
            foreach($item['attributes'] as $itemsss)
            {
              $proweight = $itemsss['value'];
            }


            $convals = 0;
            foreach($item['_conditions'] as $conditionf)
            {
                $convals += $conditionf['value'];
            }

            $pp = $item['price'];
            $pp1 = $proweight * $shipping;
            $pp2 = $pp + $pp1;
            //end calculation
              $item_details[] = array(
                  'id'        => $item['id'],
                  'price'     => $pp2,
                  'quantity'  => $item['quantity'],
                  'name'      => $item['name'],
              );
          }
```

And saved my `$item['price']` from front-end as full price with all conditions/coupons added into it, in that case i don't have to calculate conditions price in my payment function is already saved as my item price. :)

thanks for all helps.